# Disable eventlistener temporarily till animation completes

Tags: actionscript

I'm working on a basic flash fight game. I'm not a developer so i'm new to actionscript except that i have some background knowledge about coding from my course. 
The problem is-
There are about 6 fighting moves and i want to disable all 6 key_down events till the animation completes. And all 6 animations have different time frames. Can some1 just help me out with this?

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterKeyHandler);
function enterKeyHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
       if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.B) {
        gotoAndPlay(252);}

       if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.V) {
        gotoAndPlay(259);}
```

I have put down only 2 of them but there 6 in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a public static flag , ex: 
keyboardDisabled:Boolean = false;

While you play your animations you could set this to true, and inside the function which listens to keyboard events just check if keyboard is disabled and return right away.

Some code would look like

```
public static var keyboardDisabled:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterKeyHandler);
function enterKeyHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {

       if ( keyboardDisabled )
         return;

       if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.B) {
        gotoAndPlay(252);}

       if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.V) {
        gotoAndPlay(259);
}
```

Then in the frame where your animation begin

```
keyboardDisabled = true;
```

And on animation end

```
keyboardDisabled = false;
```

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKED! 
But i dont have a class or package so "var keyboardDisabled:Boolean = false;" worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Cool! glad I could give you the solution